# Catch Error/Exception In For Loop Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a loop that dynamically generates a materialized view refresh. However, I know its possible for links to become outdated, or even for materialized views to be deleted as time goes on.

I'd like to catch any errors in this loop so that it continues if there is an error.

```
for dbname in (    select distinct db_nm from app_own ) loop 
    dbms_mview.refresh('MV_' || dbname.db_nm || '_ReTable', method => 'C', atomic_refresh=> true);

end loop;
```

The below is what I normally use to catch errors... I've placed it inside the loop below, however I get an error telling me the Exception line is not what was expected. Placing this piece of code directly after the end loop results in catching one error, but not all. How can I utilize this loop and the exception piece below to catch and continue through the whole loop?

```
EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        l_errcode    := SQLCODE;
        l_errmessage := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,50);
        INSERT INTO log_table (program, code, message, info)
          VALUES (l_this_prog, l_errcode, l_errmessage, 'procedure had an error while running ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a nested block inside your loop:

```
for dbname in (    select distinct db_nm from app_own ) loop 
    begin
        dbms_mview.refresh('MV_' || dbname.db_nm || '_ReTable', method => 'C', atomic_refresh=> true);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            l_errcode    := SQLCODE;
            l_errmessage := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,50);
            INSERT INTO log_table (program, code, message, info)
            VALUES (l_this_prog, l_errcode, l_errmessage,
                'procedure had an error while running ');
    end;
end loop;
```

The exception handler is local to its block, so it only applies to the procedure call between the inner `begin` and `end`. If the procedure call does throw an exception, the handler will log that, and execution will continue after that inner block's `end` - in this case right at the end of the loop, so it will go around the loop again and process the next cursor row.

Comment: Should have mentioned, I have additional code after this loop. When I do as you suggeted, the rest of the code does not seem to fire. When I do not utilize exception handling at all, I get the expected output but I lose my fail safe. How can I get the rest of the procedure to fire?

Comment: My apologies, I had an additional exception clause at the end (doing both solutions I proposed in the question at once). Your addition and explanation make sense, I can't beileve that was my error. Thanks!

Comment: @ZAX - not sure what you mean. An exception from the procedure call will cause your error logging code to run, but will then carry on; it has no effect on anything after the loop. Oh... OK, but you aren't propagating the exception from this inner handler, so it wouldn't hit an outer exception hander even if you had one.